# Formula to split JSON inside a Google Sheet cell into multiple rows

Tags: arrays, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below JSON in a Google Sheet cell that I would like to split into multiple rows. Can anyone suggest a way to do this via a formula?

```
[{"links":"","links-href":"https://twitter.com/"},{"links":"","links-href":"https://cnn.com"}]
```

Specifically I would like the "links-href" split into different rows. I.e.

```
https://twitter.com/
https://cnn.com
```

Should be in 2 separate rows. Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the next formula can help you

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(transpose(SPLIT(K1,",{",FALSE,TRUE)),"links-href"":""(.*?)""}"))`

[image]